# Javascript - Get array value from string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was wondering if there was any way to get a value of an array, based on a string, and display the next value in the array.

```
<p id="current">page1</p>

<p id="next"></p>

<script>
var page = ["page1", "page2", "page3", "page4", "page5"];
if(document.getElementById("current") == page[0]){
  document.getElementById("next").innerhtml = page[1]
};
</script>
```

That's what I have as the general idea. However, it would be a lot of if statements, and it wouldn't look pretty. So I was wondering if there would be a way to replicate this sort of function, without it including too many if statements.

Comment: Get the numeric value from the current page and then use that as the index for the page in the array. ie getting the 1 from page one and using that as an index would lead to the next page = `page[1]`. Or use a loop to see what page is the current page and then the next item in the array is the next page.

Comment: Use a for loop to iterate over the array & use if condition.

Comment: `document.getElementById("next").innerhtml = page[++page.indexOf(document.getElementById("current").innerhtml)]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining code with comments makes for a great way to learn:

```
// This is the list of pages you have.
var pages = ["page1", "page2", "page3", "page4", "page5"];

// We use the innerText attribute of the #current node to find out
// what the current page is as a string.
var current = document.getElementById("current").innerText;

// Use the indexOf method of pages to get the index of the current
// page in the list of pages.
var index = pages.indexOf(current);

// Now, check if there is a next page. We do so by checking if current
// is not the last page in the list, or rather, there is at least one
// more page in the list.
if (index < pages.length - 1) {

  // If so, we set next to that page. Note that you can put an
  // expression for the key when using bracket notation here!
  var next = pages[index + 1];

} else {

  // Otherwise, use other text.
  var next = "No more pages :(";

}

// Now set the innerHTML of the #next node to the value of next.
document.getElementById("next").innerHTML = next;
```

Comment: You're a star! Thanks for the comments on the code too, it's really helpful, and works like a charm :)

Comment: Thanks, no problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `.indexOf` method ([more info](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp)) to find the array index of the element you're looking for.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/0fu3dydy/

**JavaScript**

```
var page = ["page1", "page2", "page3", "page4", "page5"];
var currentPageIndex = page.indexOf(document.getElementById("current").innerHTML);

if (currentPageIndex < page.length - 1) {
    document.getElementById("next").innerHTML = page[currentPageIndex + 1];
} else {
    // Do something when the current element is also the last
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just include a for statement

```
<p id="current">page1</p>

<p id="next"></p>

<script>
var page = ["page1", "page2", "page3", "page4", "page5"];
for (i=0;i=page.length-1;i++) {
   if(document.getElementById("current") == page[i]){
    document.getElementById("next").innerhtml = page[i+1]
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `indexOf()` function when you multiple values in array.

```
var currentIndex = page.indexOf(document.getElementById("current").textContent);
if(currentIndex > -1){
   if((currentIndex + 1) == page.length){
      // for last element
   }else{
     document.getElementById("next").innerhtml = page[currentIndex + 1];
   }
}
```